# jQuery drag and drop div container in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working on having the ability to drag my posts into categories; I'm using jQuery functions for the draggable and droppable effect. However, using the jQuery below fro droppable gives me an error in rails;

```
$(".display_type").droppable({
        accept: ".brand_span",
        hoverClass: "active",
        drop: function(event, props) {
          $("#display_container").load("brand_display/change",
              {drag_id: $(props.draggable).attr("id"),
               drop_id: $(this).attr("id")});
        }
  });
```

The Error message I'm getting;

```
SyntaxError: reserved word "function"
```

I know I have to rewrite it for Coffee JS... do i do?

```
$(".display_type").droppable({
        accept: ".brand_span",
        hoverClass: "active",
        drop: -> (event, props) {
          $("#display_container").load("brand_display/change",
              {drag_id: $(props.draggable).attr("id"),
               drop_id: $(this).attr("id")});
        }
  });
```

Comment: You must have done something wrong. `function` in js.erb is totally legit, Rails doesn't care those outside of Ruby code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by converting the above to Coffee norm;

```
 $(".label").droppable
  accept: ".entry"
  hoverClass: "active"
  drop: (event, props) ->
     $("#content").load "brand_display/change",
      drag_id: $(props.draggable).attr("id")
      drop_id: $(this).attr("id")
```